# Ruby-DBI MSSQL - When I try to make a select sentence, I only get nils as a results

Tags: ruby, sql-server, database, dbi, null

I want to execute a simple query using Ruby-DBI, but all the results are nil.
The query should return 6 rows that I have inserted into the DB.

My code:

```
conn = DBI.connect("DBI:ODBC:myODBC", user, password)
sql = "select S.Name, S.InternalName, from sites S where S.IsEnabled = 1"

sth = conn.select_all(sql)

while row=sth.fetch do
    p row
end

conn.disconnect if conn
```

When I execute the result is:

```
nil
nil
nil
nil
nil
nil
```

So, It seems like Ruby-DBI retrieves the 6 results but I don't know why all the results are nil.
I'm running the code from Windows 7 and Ruby 2.0.0. 32bits

I tried the Microsoft tool: sqlrun.exe and that tool returns the results correctly, so the query and the connection settings is supposed to be fine.

Any light here? May be a ruby-dbi issue?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found the problem, but I found a workaround.
Rather than using dbi lib, using odbc directly seems to work.

You can find a tutorial using odbc in ruby here:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3896.connect-to-windows-azure-sql-database-from-ruby-applications.aspx